# Run task on Models datetime in django

Tags: python, django

I`m working on a project and can`t solve, probably, a simple issue.

I have some datetime in a Model and I need to run some code when the current time reaches the Model datetime, so to say it is a sheduler with the provision from Models, also there is need to add some occurancies like every day, year, ...

I wonder if there is a simple nice solution.

Thanks forward....

Comment: try [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: I`ve heard about it, could you provide a short example

Comment: @E.Tretyakov If you read the docs of celery you can find how to setup celery. There is simple example available as how to run a task periodically.

Comment: As others suggested, try celery, or make a script and setup a cronjob(if you are in Linux)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have two solutions.

The simplest one is to create management commands to do what you need to do, and use the `django.utils.timezone.now` as starting value to filter your datetime in the models. You can create many commands as you wish like

- run_hourly
- run_daily
- run_weekly

Then you can setup cron on linux to run the management commands when you need it.

Another solution is to use a task queues tool like `Celery` or `RQ`.
Celery needs to be configured and you must also setup your server to run `Celery` and the `Celery beat schedule` to run the tasks at specific time. If you don't have any specific requirements and your needs is just run a couple of tasks I would use `cron` instead of any Task Queues

More about Task Queues software here: https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found extremely usefull [article](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/02/how-to-install-celery-on-django-and.html). Everything works fine but PyCharm detects failure importing these

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
```

But still it doesn`t gives an error during server running.

Comment: replaced by this from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task